# When is the Connectivity Change Broadcast triggered in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, connectivity

I have an issue.

I have got the connectivity change broadcast registered in Activity A's onResume(). I am unregistering it in the onPause().

Now, say I am on Activity B. Hence, Activity A is in the onStop() and the broadcast is unregistered. 
When I come back to Activity A from B, it registers the connectivity change broadcast and the broadcast is triggered simultaneously.

The connectivity has not changed at all. I am using mobile data.
Secondly, I am not notifying for the broadcast as well to trigger the onReceive(). Is it because it is a system-level broadcast, it calls the onReceive()?

I may have misunderstood the concept. Hence, need clarification for the same.

```
onResume()
{
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(android.net.ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
}
```

Comment: yes it will broadcast whenever you will come to A, because onResume always runs...for more info please show your code here...